# Remove or permanently disable the Google Now notification bell & popups in Chrome (on desktop)

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, notifications

Google had enabled notifications in Chrome some time back, now they have enabled desktop popups that are linked to Google Now feature. How do I disable it?

**Update** Clarifying a bit. Permanently disable chrome notifications & get rid of the bell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update :** Doesn't work anymore

Go to `chrome://flags/` , search for `Now` & select `Disabled` from the drop-down menu.

[image]

Comment: Now, you need to disable the `Enable experimental UI for Notifications` and `Enable Rich Notifications` in `chrome://flags/`

Comment: I don't see this on Chrome `36.0.1985.125 m` on Windows 7

Comment: Sorry, I was on `34.0.1847.45 beta-m` on Win7. Updating now :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google is trying to settle on a name for the flags that control this new feature.

On version 36.0.1985.143 m for Windows, the relevant flags under chrome://flags are "Enable Synced Notifications" and "Device Discovery Notifications". Set these to "disabled", and the bell disappears from the taskbar completely.

Let's hope that it sticks through future updates.

Comment: Setting these to enabled and restarting Chrome turns it back on, if you've accidentally killed it like I did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you asked for (Chrome internal vs. desktop notifications) but have you tried to disable the notifications from the bell icon in the system tray? (see screenshot)
You can disable all the notifications (crossed bell) or just those from specific applications (under the gear icon you have also Google Now).

[image]

Comment: Permanently disable... it keeps coming back with that menu. Bonus would be to get rid of that bell.

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable the annoying bell (notification bell) in system tray, which is created by Chrome (I think, windows versions of chrome), there were several internal flags at "chrome://flags/" url (search for notification and then for now, disable all found). But since around 31-34 versions of Chrome, disabling doesn't work; for example by going to "youtube", opening any "FAIL COMPILATION" video in full-screen mode, and the hell's bell is shown again.

One of top cyberhackers from Russia has the heavy artillery method: http://habrahabr.ru/post/225945/ (Убиваем «колокольчик» от Google Chrome в трее = Killing the "notification bell" from Google Chrome at system tray). The method is binary patching of "chrome.dll" file (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application, or Application Data\Local Settings\Google\Chrome\Application\ then go to newest version). The patch can be applied with any hex editor, open the chrome.dll, search for FF15C0D77103 (binary code shown as hex string), then replace the string with 585833C09090 (again, the actual binary code encoded as hex). The hacker says he had 8 replaces.

PS: the binary patch must be reapplied after every Chrome update.

Comment: That is one hell of a determination to beat the bell. Personally, I'm not so comfortable with binary patching my browser considering that it's the primary medium for sending & receiving all my personal/financial information. I'd live with the bell until an official hook shows up.

Comment: buffer, the binary patch is simple as safe. It just disables calling the  Shell_NotifyIcon WinAPI function.